# What type of layout to use for RCP GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm creating my GUI for my RCP application using a `GridLayout` but I'm coming across problems because from what I understand a `GridLayout` adds elements in the order you create them/set their layout data? So, this doesn't offer a lot/any flexibility for moving elements around and adding new elements whilst keeping the same layout of previously placed elements.

Is there any other approach I should be using to make my GUI? I need it to be flexible and easy to specify the size and location of individual components rather than the component going in the next space.

At the moment`GridLayout` only allows me to specify the number of columns on the screen then specify the elements attributes (`SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER`) etc.

Here's my code to show what I mean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class CreateUI {

//Text area for the variables
Text variableArea;
Text methodArea;
Text otherArea;
Text fooArea;

@PostConstruct
//Annotation indicates the method is to be called after the class is constructed
public void createInterface(Composite parent){

    int columns =4;

    //Set the layout of the parent (the Part) to a grid layout
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(columns, true));

    variableArea = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    variableArea.setText("Hello");
    variableArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

    methodArea = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    methodArea.setText("Hello2");
    methodArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

    otherArea = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    otherArea.setText("Hello3");
    otherArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

    fooArea = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    fooArea.setText("Hello4");
    fooArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));


  }
}
```

This produces this:

[image]

At the moment there's only those 4 Text areas there as an example but I'm going to have multiple Text areas, Buttons, Drop Down Menu's etc later on and I want to be able to format them easier and position them freely.

In relation to the above example I want to be able to position those 4 Text areas on top of one another in a column to display information and have other elements positioned freely in the remaining space.

Any pointers would be great for what I should be using.

Comment: I think `GridLayout` is the best choice. Read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

[`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/) is quite flexible. From built-in layouts, `FormLayout` is also a decent choice, but it's quite a bit harder to get right than `GridLayout`, so I'd only recommend using it if you find `GridLayout` really unsuitable.

Comment: Is there any advantage of `MigLayout` over `GridLayout` that justifies using an additional library?

Comment: @Baz 1. Not being limited to a grid (obviously). 2. Even when using a grid, easily changing what cell components are placed in (instead of, e.g., filling places with empty `Composite`s and having to change their number often). See http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/whitepaper.html and consider how much of this can be done in GridLayout/FormLayout and with how much effort. Again, if the standard layouts do satisfy your requirements, use them; if they don't, use another and then `MigLayout` is a very nice option.